# Beautiful Soup returning 'None' even though element exists in tag

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the price of airpods in officeworks, but can't seem to get anything out of it.

I tried finding the div that the span class was in that held the price and tried to find that and return it.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def PriceOfficeWorks(URL):
        HEADERS = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'
        }
        page = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS, timeout=10)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
        price = soup.find('div', class_='sc-TOsTZ jxBJfl')
        finalprice = price.find('span')
        return finalprice

print(PriceOfficeWorks("https://www.officeworks.com.au/shop/officeworks/p/apple-airpods-with-charging-case-2nd-gen-amv7n2zaa"))
```

Comment: Which URL?  Don't make us guess.  Otherwise, we can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Why do you import selenium, if you don’t use it?

Comment: What have you done to troubleshoot this yourself? If you save the response to disk, does it actually contain the div?

Answer (score 0):

If I `print(page)` it shows that the status code is 405, and `page.text` shows that it's asking for you to solve a captcha.

In general, check what your code is 'seeing' and don't assume that it's the same as what you get in the browser.